# Compiling angular directive in test fails even after running digest()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to test a directive in angular but the compilation is not working, even after I run `$scope.$digest()`.

The directive's template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <knob>...</knob>
    <knob>...</knob>
    <knob>...</knob>
</div>
```

And the test looks something like this:

```
describe('DirectiveTest', function() {

    beforeEach(module('AppTestModule'));

    var directiveElem, $scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $q, $injector, $templateCache) {

        $scope = $rootScope.new();

        $scope.parameter1 = {};
        $scope.parameter2 = {};
        $scope.parameter3 = false;

        directiveElem = angular.element('<my-directive param1="parameter1" param2="parameter2" param3="parameter3"></my-directive>');
        $compile(directiveElem)($scope);

        $scope.$digest();

    }));

    it('should have three knobs', function() {
        $scope.$digest();
        console.log('directiveElem = ', directiveElem);
        var knobs = directiveElem.find('knob');
        expect(knobs.length).toEqual(3);
    });

});
```

The test fails (it doesn't find any `knob` elements) because the directive is not being compiled.

The `console.log` prints something like this:

```
directiveElem = ', {0: <my-directive param1="parameter1" param2="parameter2" param3="parameter3" class="ng-scope"></my-directive>, length: 1}
```

(It only adds class="ng-scope")

It's worth noting that I'm using the ng-html2js karma preprocessor and that I found in Chrome that the template is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using `angular.element(...)`. I generally use something like this:

```
var elementHtml = '<my-directive></my-directive>';
element = $compile(elementHtml)(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

To see the generated html, you would use:

```
console.log(element.html());
```

Comment: I think I have tried multiple examples, they do it in different ways. I tried like you say and I got the same error.

Comment: @miguel It should also be `$rootScope.$new()`, instead of `new()`. Does that help?